# Spring Boot useTestClasspath throws CannotLoadBeanClassException and ClassNotFoundException

Tags: spring-boot, maven-plugin

I have a maven project with a test class located at `src/test/java/MyDevClass` which is intended for development/testing purposes only. I would like to use it when I start [spring-boot-maven-plugin](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/run-mojo.html) with the command line `mvn spring-boot:run`.

So, my `pom.xml` contains:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <!-- TODO: Will create a maven profile and have useTestClasspath only for development/testing -->
                <useTestClasspath>true</useTestClasspath>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

But, I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [MyDevClass]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MyDevClass
```

Intriguing enough, I have another project using [tomcat7-maven-plugin](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.1/tomcat7-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html) and it works fine:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <useTestClasspath>true</useTestClasspath>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

***What I am missing?***

Comment: I don't understand. Why you want to have it registered in production context when it is test class? Doesn't make sense.

Comment: Unrelated but [don't put your app in the default package](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-using-the-default-package).

Comment: Hi @luboskrnac. Correct, I don't want it in production. I will create a maven profile for that.

Comment: Hi Stephane Nicoll, no problem. I left in default package for simplicity sake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring-boot maven plugin does not include current module's test sources (and resources) into classpath even if `useTestClasspath` is set to true.

I ran a forked execution with verbose logging (`-X` flag to Maven), and the plugin listed the forked JVM classpath. Test classes were not included.

If you look at the plugin [sources](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/maven/AbstractRunMojo.java) (version 1.5.3 at time of writing), the flag `useTestClasspath` is only used in the `addDependencies` method.

I see two options as workarounds

1. Add the `target/test-classes` dir to the run classpath:

   ```
   <directories>
     <directory>${project.build.testOutputDirectory}</directory>
   </directories>
   ```

   For older plugin version use:

   ```
   <folders>
     <folder>${project.build.testOutputDirectory}</folder>
   </folders>
   ```

   The problem here is that the folder is added to the beginning of classpath, while test files are preferable at its end.
2. Create another Maven module with test classes and resources, and add it as a `<scope>test</scope>` dependency.

Comment: I end up doing something similar to your suggestion #2

Comment: Thanks, the solution works zajebiscie :P